# Printing Even Matrix Diagonal

Tags: java, arrays, crash, nested

I have a problem involving matrices, what I need to do is fill an m by n matrix (that is, m rows and n columns), with even numbers in a diagonal pattern.

example: [Required Output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VMGAqMF11Qd1h84e0xO2F2ucwIIrsR1Z)

I came up with the following code, but I can not make the series increase diagonally, also when the matrix is square (for example a 4 by 4 matrix) the program runs normally, but otherwise, if it is m by n I get an error.

My code:

```
    int val;
    int lonv;
    int fil;
    int col;
    int su=2;
    int matriz[][];
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de filas para la matriz: ");
    fil=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de columnas para la matriz: ");
    col=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    matriz=new int [fil][col];
    for(int i=0; i<fil; i++)
    {
        for(int j=(col-1); j>=0; j-- )
        {
            if(matriz[i][j]<= 2)
            {
                matriz[i][j]= su;
                su+=2;
            }
            else
            {

                System.out.println("");
                matriz[i][j]= su;
                su+=2;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<col; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

[Test Case 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zQY8TGZa1ur88LNzT3L1A3KWNp9hVs6J): error

[Test Case 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C7oK84if4O6CfC68HfjH06_K8PTttLa7): Failed to print in the required diagonal format

Answer (score 0):

## Error

#### The second nested loop

You are getting an indexoutofbounds error for an m by n matrix because your second nested loop depends strictly on the size of the columns, implying that for it to run smoothly the matrix would have to be square:

```
for(int i=0; i<col; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

## Your error case

#### n > m error

An error will occur when n > m. If the number of columns is greater than the number of rows (n > m) then you would be trying to access data that has not been created because you initialized it rightfully as an m by n matrix in the line:

```
matriz=new int [fil][col];
```

## Solution

Assuming you correctly inserted the values of an m by n matrix, just print the matrix for what it is (an m by n matrix rather than an n by n) like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<fil; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

## Printing Diagonal

Information regarding printing an array diagonally can be found at: http://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2016/12/print-matrix-diagonally-or-diagonal.html

The logic should be very transferable.

Comment: ok that's sound good, but the numbers do not follow the sequence diagonally, as I can fix it

Comment: @GameGeneration this may help for that: http://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2016/12/print-matrix-diagonally-or-diagonal.html